# trouble Adding two numbers in android

Tags: android

### Finding trouble calculating the addition of two numbers

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText FirstNumber,SecondNumber;
    Button CalculateValue;
    TextView Result;
    int x,y,z;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        FindAllTheViews();


        CalculateValue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                CalculateTheSum();
            }
        });

    }

    private void FindAllTheViews() {
        FirstNumber=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.First_Number);
        SecondNumber=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Second_Number);
        CalculateValue=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Calculate_Button);
        Result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Final_Result);
    }

    private void CalculateTheSum() {
        x=new Integer(FirstNumber.getText().toString());
        y=new Integer(SecondNumber.getText().toString());
        z=x+y;
        Result.setText(z);
    }

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/First_Number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Second_Number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/First_Number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="WELCOME"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Second-Number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:text="First-Number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Calculate_Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Second_Number"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Second_Number"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Calculate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Final_Result"
        android:text="The result is::"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Final_Result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Calculate_Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Calculate_Button"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:text="Result"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Log**

```
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x64
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2857)
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.example.addingtwonumbers.MainActivity.CalculateTheSum(MainActivity.java:49)
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.example.addingtwonumbers.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:45)
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.example.addingtwonumbers.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:32)
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-11 14:46:22.794: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Integer.toString(z);` to convert z to a String!

Answer (score 1):

`TextView.setText` exists in 2 flavors. One takes a String and displays it literally, the other takes an int, and uses it as an id to find the appropriate resource.

You are using the second one to display the sum of your numbers.

You need to convert your int in String first.

Also, you'll notice that the issue is not with the actual addition, as the result is displayed in the stacktrace you posted (0x64).

Extra tip : to solve this kind of issue, google the error message, read the documentation of the method used at the crashing line (`MainActivity.java:49`)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are trying to put integer into textview. Usually, object can be "converted" to String by using method `.toString()` without need to call it explicitly. In your case, there is method `TextView.setText(int resourceId)`, where integer is pointing to some resource defined in XML.

For your case, you can use `Integer.toString(z)` or `String.valueOf(z)` (which is effectively the same)

Answer (score 0):

z is an integer, so you are calling  `setText (int resid)` which tries to load a resource , since there are no resources with id = z it throws an error.
Try to use `setText ("" + z)` to call `setText (CharSequence text)`

Answer (score 0):

EditText.setText(int resId) is not set resId to EditText, but set what resId refers.try Result.setText(String.valueOf(z)).
And there exist some unsafe actions.